# What's the name of this Apple monitor

Tags: apple-ii, crt-monitor

Browsing through retrocomputing resources, I recently stumbled upon this picture:

[image: unknown Apple monitor]

I'm familiar with quite a few Apple II monitors, but it's the first time I saw this one. There's an Apple logo, so it should be an official Apple monitor, but which one? Bonus points if some resource can be found such as a user's or service manual (I just fell in love with the monitor's design and I'm looking for a technical drawing, or its dimensions, so I can attempt to create a 3D model.)

**EDIT:** Found the [Owner's Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/download/1795213/Nec-Jb-1201mr.html), following Jim Withrow's answer. I guess the Apple logo was added by the owner.

Comment: Yea, that monitor does have a 'retro-vibe' and pairs with the Apple ][+ nicely.

Comment: The apple logo doesn't look centred, unlike the light and controls below it. Seems very much like a sticker added by the owner.

Comment: It is quite possible that the monitor is an official Apple product, despite being manufactured by someone else.  It was not uncommon for companies to rebrand other companies products.  The two companies would be referred to as the "Value Added Reseller" (VAR, = Apple) and the "Original Equipment Manufacturer" (OEM, = NEC).  In this case, what Apple would be adding is A) the logo and B) packaging it with the computer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NEC Character Display, Model JB-1201M(A).

It’s a 12” monochrome green display, manufactured in Japan circa 1981. Approximate dimensions are 14” x 12” x 11 1/2”.

Further details found at:

https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/X2053.2001B

Comment: Hi and welcome. As well as the link, it would be better to [edit] your answer and also include the *details* from the link (there aren't that many), in the case of [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Comment: It cannot be a monochrome computer screen, as it shows not only green text there.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah That'll be an artefact of the photography, as the Apple II isn't capable of displaying colour text in the way you're interpreting it.

Comment: @AlexTaylor: More generally, it's very common for bright greens in photographs to become yellow or cyan, bright reds to become yellow or magenta, and for bright blues to become cyan or magenta.  What happens is that a color which on a 0-255 scale would appear as e.g. (200,600,50) [i.e. with the green value being 3x the red value]  if it wasn't clipped instead shows up as (200,255,50) [with green only slightly higher than red].